# Multiple belongsTo creates caching error

Tags: caching, cakephp-1.3

I'm upgrading an existing application from CakePHP 1.2 to 1.3.  A simplified version of one of the models looks like:

```
class Load extends AppModel {

 var $belongsTo = array(
     'OriginCity' => array(
     'className' => 'City',
     'foreignKey' => 'origin_city_id',
     'conditions' => '',
     'fields' => '',
     'order' => '',
  ),
     'DestinationCity' => array(
    'className' => 'City',
    'foreignKey' => 'destination_city_id',
    'conditions' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => '',
     )
   );
 }
```

When I bring up a listing of my "Loads" models, it works fine the first time, but after that, I get:

```
 Catchable fatal error: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string in /home/mike/Projects/myapp/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 554
```

If I manually remove the cache, it works fine.

I started deleting the files in `app/tmp/cache/persistent` one at a time, and it works after the `load.php` file is deleted.  If I do `php load.php` it returns without error or anything (so I assume that it works).

My theory is that it works fine the first time but when Cake 1.3 gets the Load's cache, it tries to look for objects name `OriginCity` and `DestinationCity` which, of course, there is none.

So what can I do with the cache to get it to behave?  Or is there a better way to get CakePHP 1.3 to point to have two different `belongsTo` to point to the same object-type?

**EDIT:**  I changed the caching method to APC and I still got he same issue.  SO I turned off caching site-wide and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of the fact that in 5.2 it is no longer possible to 
print an object e.g. "print $myObject". Instead, this will call to 
__toString(), which, if it does not exist, will cause the code to die 
with a catchable fatal error.

You can fix it by adding a __toString() to your app_controller

```
 public function __toString(){
     return "Needed to print an object";
 }
```